# Using a field value (ID) to get a TEXT value from Reference Table

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have a somewhat weird scenario with one of my tables that I'm trying to resolve. I have a table that looks like this:

```
 ID      FldVal        OldVal       NewVal
 1       Name          Bob          Robert
 2       Cost          17           21
 3       Location      32           NULL
```

OldVal and NewVal are Varchar(MAX) fields and store all field values that are updated by user. 99% of them are simply text or numeric values, some of them, like LOCATION, is actually an ID value in a Reftable that looks like this:

```
 ID       Code       Text
 1        31         Office
 2        32         Park
 3        17         Opera
```

My question is, is there any way I can join the first table with the Ref table so that it only pulls specific values. Since I might have a wide variety of values like 17, 21, i don't want them accidental to pull TEXT value from the Ref table. I only want it to do that on Location.

my goal is to get these results

```
Name Bob Robert
Cost 17 21
Location Park NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when f.fldval = 'Location' then ro.text then t.oldval end) as new_oldval,
       (case when f.fldval = 'Location' then rn.text else t.newval end) as new_newval
from t left join
     reftable ro
     on ro.code = try_convert(int, t.oldval) and
        t.fldval = 'Location' left join
     reftable rn
     on rn.code = try_convert(int, t.newval) and
        t.fldval = 'Location';
```

For backwards compatibility, you can convert to a string instead of to an integer:

```
select t.*,
       (case when f.fldval = 'Location' then ro.text then t.oldval end) as new_oldval,
       (case when f.fldval = 'Location' then rn.text else t.newval end) as new_newval
from t left join
     reftable ro
     on convert(varchar(255), ro.code) = t.oldval and
        t.fldval = 'Location' left join
     reftable rn
     on convert(varchar(255), rn.code) = t.newval and
        t.fldval = 'Location';
```

Comment: I see what you did here, but i still can't use try_convert in your joins

Comment: @Koosh . . . Why not?  It should be fine.

Comment: it says try_convert is not supported. I'm running SQL SERVER 2012 but compatibility at 2005 (90). I researched this online and shows that compatibility has to be at least 110 (2012)